# sum column counts for two different values

Tags: mysql

i have a column that can hold 6 values (1,2,3,A,B,C)

i can count(*) them so it looks like this

```
select mycol, count(*) as ttl from mytable group by mycol;
    mycol  ttl
    1       46
    2       53
    3       10
    A       5 
    B       4
    C       2
```

but i want to sum the 1s and the As, and the 2s and the Bs like this

```
mycol total
var1    51
var2    57
var3    12
```

will a case statement work for this?  like case 1 or A then treat them the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a `case` statement will work for this:

```
select (case when mycol in ('1', 'var1') then 'var1'
             when mycol in ('2', 'var2') then 'var2'
             when mycol in ('3', 'var3') then 'var3'
        end),
       sum(ttl) as Total
from mytable t
group by (case when mycol in ('1', 'var1') then 'var1'
               when mycol in ('2', 'var2') then 'var2'
               when mycol in ('3', 'var3') then 'var3'
          end);
```

EDIT:

If you just have the data with multiple rows for each value:

```
select (case when mycol in ('1', 'var1') then 'var1'
             when mycol in ('2', 'var2') then 'var2'
             when mycol in ('3', 'var3') then 'var3'
        end),
       count(*) as Total
from mytable t
group by (case when mycol in ('1', 'var1') then 'var1'
               when mycol in ('2', 'var2') then 'var2'
               when mycol in ('3', 'var3') then 'var3'
          end);
```

Comment: `GROUP BY 1` would be prittier ;)

Comment: @jaczes . . . Yes, that is prettier.  But it is not standard SQL and supported by few SQL engines.